# Parsing CSV to 2 dimensions array

Tags: python, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a samples.csv files and this archive has this structure:

```
354,174,27c,20,5c,287,382,a3
59,359,152,115,19d,15a,143,113
8f,1e6,291,55,b1,3f9,39b,ba
3cf,77,20c,316,164,e2,2cb,3c9
72,171,167,a9,3e5,2dc,34f,191
2ad,8c,1f1,1bd,175,3fd,28,2f5
3b1,11f,ab,8b,282,284,192,1c8
310,24b,240,1fe,20e,251,1d5,305
3f1,14b,381,210,1b4,25f,116,228
ba,175,1c2,342,259,de,359,369
```

Its a 8 x 1000 samples, and i want convert this csv to 2 dimensions array to extract the data this form:

```
[i,j]

354 = [0,0]
174 = [0,1]
```

How do it that without numpy?

Thanks

Comment: store the file as a string...split that string by new line characters...split the strings in that result by comma

Comment: Do you want to override Python's normal matrix access of `matrix[0][0]` to be `matrix[0,0]`? That is not the standard way to access a 2 dimensional list in Python. It can be done -- but maybe get used to Python's way first?

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built-in module for parsing csv files, called `csv`. Here is an example from the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

You can store that as a list of lists:

```
rows = []
for row in spamreader:
    rows.append(row)
print rows[5][3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = file('samples.csv').read()
table = [row.split(',') for row in data.split('\n')]

print table[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert each row into a list, and then add them to another list to get your matrix:

```
import csv

matrix = []

with open('somefile.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
   matrix.append(list(reader))

print(matrix[0][1])  # Output: 174
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
array = []
for line in f:
    array.append(line.split(','))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv and a list comprehension:

```
import csv

with open(ur_file) as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    data=[row for row in reader]

print data
# [['354', '174', '27c', '20', '5c', '287', '382', 'a3'], ['59', '359', '152', '115', '19d', '15a', '143', '113'], ['8f', '1e6', '291', '55', 'b1', '3f9', '39b', 'ba'], ['3cf', '77', '20c', '316', '164', 'e2', '2cb', '3c9'], ['72', '171', '167', 'a9', '3e5', '2dc', '34f', '191'], ['2ad', '8c', '1f1', '1bd', '175', '3fd', '28', '2f5'], ['3b1', '11f', 'ab', '8b', '282', '284', '192', '1c8'], ['310', '24b', '240', '1fe', '20e', '251', '1d5', '305'], ['3f1', '14b', '381', '210', '1b4', '25f', '116', '228'], ['ba', '175', '1c2', '342', '259', 'de', '359', '369']]
print data[0][0]  
# 354
```

Your question implies that you want to access the data using a tuple `data[0,1]` vs a multidimensional list that you would use the syntax of `data[0][1]`

If that is not a typo, you can use a dictionary with a two element tuple as keys:

```
>>> data={}
>>> data[0,0]='354'
>>> data
{(0, 0): '354'}
>>> data[0,0]
'354'
```

Your loop to read the csv then becomes:

```
data={}
with open(ur_file) as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        for j, v in enumerate(line):
            data[(i, j)]=v

print data
# {(7, 3): '1fe', (4, 7): '191', (1, 3): '115', (9, 1): '175', (6, 4): '282', (3, 0): '3cf', (8, 0): '3f1', (5, 4): '175', (0, 7): 'a3', (5, 6): '28', (2, 6): '39b', (1, 6): '143', (9, 4): '259', (5, 1): '8c', (3, 7): '3c9', (2, 5): '3f9', (8, 5): '25f', (0, 3): '20', (7, 2): '240', (4, 0): '72', (1, 2): '152', (9, 0): 'ba', (9, 5): 'de', (6, 7): '1c8', (3, 3): '316', (2, 0): '8f', (8, 1): '14b', (7, 6): '1d5', (4, 4): '3e5', (6, 3): '8b', (1, 5): '15a', (3, 6): '2cb', (2, 2): '291', (7, 7): '305', (5, 7): '2f5', (5, 3): '1bd', (4, 1): '171', (1, 1): '359', (9, 7): '369', (2, 7): 'ba', (3, 2): '20c', (0, 0): '354', (6, 6): '192', (5, 0): '2ad', (7, 1): '24b', (4, 5): '2dc', (0, 4): '5c', (5, 5): '3fd', (1, 4): '19d', (6, 0): '3b1', (7, 5): '251', (2, 3): '55', (2, 1): '1e6', (8, 7): '228', (8, 6): '116', (9, 3): '342', (4, 2): '167', (1, 0): '59', (9, 6): '359', (6, 5): '284', (3, 5): 'e2', (0, 1): '174', (8, 3): '210', (7, 0): '310', (4, 6): '34f', (9, 2): '1c2', (5, 2): '1f1', (6, 1): '11f', (3, 1): '77', (8, 2): '381', (0, 2): '27c', (7, 4): '20e', (0, 6): '382', (6, 2): 'ab', (4, 3): 'a9', (1, 7): '113', (0, 5): '287', (3, 4): '164', (2, 4): 'b1', (8, 4): '1b4'}
print data[0,1]   
# 174
```